# Send attachment with PhpMailer with path chosen by the user

Tags: php, email, pdf, phpmailer, fpdf

I'm trying to send some emails using PHPMailer and I'd like to attach a pdf file to them. The name of this file has to be selected from the user into a select tag in html. In particular this is the code receiving the input

```
<select name="Attachment">
                <?php
                    $files=scandir("/pathtotherightfolder/");
                    for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++)
                    {
                        if(substr($files[$i],-3,3)=="pdf")
                        echo "<option value='".$files[$i]."'>".$files[$i]."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                <option value="Nessuno">Nessuno</option>
 </select>
```

This input is received from another php file which will send the emails and it's working correctly except for the attachment part, I tried all the ways suggested by tutorials, documentation, forums like

1st:

```
      $url="URL of the correct directory in my website".$_POST['Attachment'];
        $messaggio->AddStringAttachment(file_get_content($url), $_POST['Attachment'], $encoding='base64' , $type='application/pdf');//this one returns FALSE and sends the email with a corrupted attachment, and sends a warning of bad request...adding $_POST['Attachment']=str_replace(" ","%20",$_POST['Attachment']); it still returns false but it doesn't send the email
```

Also adding

```
chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($url)));
```

2nd:

```
$url="Samepathofthehtml".$_POST['Attachment'];//this path is correct
$messaggio->AddAttachment(realpath($url), $_POST['Attachment'], $encoding='base64' , $type='application/pdf');//this one returns bool(false) and sends the email with no attachments
```

3rd:

```
require("fpdf.php");
require("fpdi.php");

$pdf = new FPDI();

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("Samepathasbefore".$_POST['Attachment']);
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);//just a try with one page
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 90);
$doc = $pdf->Output('', 'S');//if I try $pdf->Output(); i see the pdf correctly on my browser (so i deduce all the previous instructions are correct)
//And in the sending code
$messaggio->AddStringAttachment($doc, $_POST['Attachment'], $encoding='base64' , $type='application/pdf');//I obtain the same return value of the 2nd
```

In the 1st and 3rd case I receive the Attachment but the content is corrupted, in the 2nd I receive the mail without the attachment.
Does someone has already tried to do something similar? Any advice?

Comment: It looks like you've based your code on an obsolete example, so make sure you're using the latest version. You say it's not working, but don't show how. The second method is the most straightforward, and there are many examples provided that do the same thing without a problem - please post the raw message source you receive. Don't try encoding the attachment yourself, you'll just break things - PHPMailer does all that for you.

Comment: @Synchro: I've shown how: "In the 1st and 3rd case I receive the Attachment but the content is corrupted, in the 2nd I receive the mail without the attachment." and I've tried many variations of the second method (which is actually the most documented) but some examples doesn't even send the email and some other send the email without attachment

Comment: No, you show your code, but you're not showing error messages, and you're not checking your return values.

Comment: @Synchro: I'm sorry sir, I added the return values and the errors as signalized sir (as comments in the code).

Comment: "this one returns bool(false)" - please apply a little sense - a false result means **it failed**. Either your path is incorrect or your permissions are wrong. Check all your parameter values. Fix one problem at a time.

Comment: have you checked output of `realpath($url)` ? Is it correct? And does your application has permission to read it?

Comment: @ksg91: Checking the realpath($url) I see it's correct, the AddAttachment now returns true but the mail doesn't arrive, but the Send() method doesn't give any error

Comment: Sorry to everyone, I discovered that the emails didn't arrive only on mailinator recipients, on which I was trying to send (I still don't know very well why) but tying to send to my own email it works. Sorry again.

Comment: I correct myself, it arrives SOMETIMES